# Build a slug with multiple fields

Tags: slug, bolt-cms

Normaly I use

```
slug:
    type: slug
    uses: title
```

to define the slug in a Bolt contenttype. But now I would like to define it more like this:

```
slug:
    type: slug
    uses: date+title
```

How can this be done? What is the syntax to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uses takes an array so something like this:

```
uses: [date, title]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can it be also extended by string?
Something like:

```
slug:
   type: slug
   uses: [title,weight,'kg']
```

Comment: No, you can't.
PS: You shouldn't post a follow-up question as an answer. Consider adding your question as a comment to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for advice, sorry for the wrong comment placement.

Comment: You're welcome! PS: Sorry, I didn't want to be that harsh as it might have sounded.